# How to identify the sound of an "A" without altering the spelling of the word?

Tags: pronunciation, letters-of-the-alphabet, vowels

I have the word "Carr" (short for the name Carrie).

Is there a way to write the 'a' so that a person reading the word 'Carr' would pronounce it like *care* ('kær), opposed to pronouncing it like *car* (kɑr)?

Something like Càrr, Cárr, Cãrr, etc...?

This is for an English-Speaking company name.

Comment: I don't think there is.  You'll need to do it with marketing slogans and ad campaigns.  Or write a letter to [these brothers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_Industries) and ask them how they dealt with it ;-)

Comment: Nothing that anyone would actually understand without an explanation, I don't think.

Comment: I, too, am at a loss as to how to write the _a_, but you might consider spelling the word like _Cair_. At least it would be pronounced right, and not confused with the word _care_. @Jim - I remember being in grade school when a boy name Jared was the first in our school to don a pair of Nike sneakers. The company name was on the back of the shoe; most of us initially assumed it rhymed with "Mike".

Comment: You've obviously considered replacing the letter "a" with other symbols. The fact that those others look similar to "a" isn't really relevant - they're still *different* symbols. But why cling to the misleading representation "Carr" in the first place? Your only chance there is to put *(pronounced "care")* after the first use. But if you transcribe it as "Kerr" most Anglophones will guess correctly how it's pronounced.

Comment: It may be relevant that the BrE pronunciation of Carrie is in any case not 'care-ey'. The 'a' is short, as in 'hat'.

Comment: @Fumble - I would assume "Kerr" rhymes with "her" or "fur".

Comment: @Fumble I grew up near a "Kerr Lake," pronounced "car," and just realized that that pronunciation is ridiculous for the spelling when you proposed this example.

Comment: @hunter It was a common early pronunciation of <er>--Shakespeare's Clown says *argal* for *ergo*--which endured through the 18th and into the 19th century and lingers today in *sergeant* and (BrE) *clerk*. Note the name alternations: Derby/Darby, Berkshire/Barkshire, Hertford/Hartford, Merchant/Marchant, Persons/Parsons. And think of that staple epithet of westerns, *varmint*.

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's an exact cross-post to multiple SE sites (only a minute apart, without mentioning it): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149378/how-to-identify-the-sound-of-an-a-without-altering-the-spelling-of-the-word

Comment: Though Michael should be informed that cross-posting is frowned upon and may result in question closure, I think this is probably the most appropriate site for this question so I'm not voting to close here and have even gone so far as to provide the answer. ;)

Comment: Already asked on ELU [last month](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149378/how-to-identify-the-sound-of-an-a-without-altering-the-spelling-of-the-word)

Comment: @Nico, I saw that when snailplane provided the link yesterday. I still think this is a good place for the question, as many learning English may wish to steer people towards decent pronunciation of their names. It was not _answered_ on ELU, and should probably be deleted from there.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I'm having second thoughts about closing the question, because the answers here seem more interesting.

Comment: @Nico Well, I'm voting to reopen and you're welcome to join me. I think this is a fine place for the question, and as long as Michael knows not to post things across multiple SEs in the future, we shouldn't remove something that might be useful to other users of ELL. Those with sufficient ELU rep can close the question on ELU if they don't want there to be two versions in existence. In my opinion, it should be closed on ELU regardless, but I don't have sufficient rep to vote over there.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult problem, Carrie. What about a French spelling like Cair? Actually the spelling ai for the sound in care is used in English: chair, hair, fair, lair.

Comment: The O.P.'s name is Michael, not Carrie.

Comment: @J.R. It's possible to read the answer more like ♫ "How do you solve a problem like 'Carrie'". ♫

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a macron over the 'a': "Cārr"

Even if people aren't familiar with the symbol, they will at least see it as a sign to pronounce the word differently from how they usually would and "Care" is really the only alternative.

For extra help, you could even write "Cārr(ie)", so that people understand that it is a shortened name and pronounce it as they would the first part of "Carrie".

Comment: Many reading primers use the macron (like on ā) to indicate "long" vowels (such as this one), and the breve (like on ă) to indicate "short" vowels (such as in "rat").

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to represent/invent a shortened version of a word, why not use a contraction?

> Car'e

It's a bit informal, but so are many contractions… and nicknames. But the contraction form serves to shorten the pronunciation and representation of a word while further suggesting how it should be pronounced.

That seems to fulfill your intentions here.

Answer (score -3):

English words don't end with a short syllable in a stressed position, so people will naturally lengthen it. Since your choice of name breaks the rules of English phonology, you need to specifically teach it people.

Comment: *hat, cat, sit, lip, cup, top, chair, bear, stare*?

Comment: What you ***meant*** was that English words don't end with a short syllable before an 'r' in a stressed position. This is not true for Irish, and is debatable for some American accents. For instance, if you speak with an American accent that merges *Mary* and *marry* but not *merry*, then *care* has the same sound as *carry* and *Carrie*, which you might call a *"short a"*.